# Turkish delight is way too soft and too sweet. How can I make it more firm with way less sugar?

Tags: dessert, candy

I'm following [this recipe](http://www.geniuskitchen.com/recipe/any-flavor-turkish-delight-278529) for Turkish delight.

There are a few unwanted outcomes. First, is the instructions for preparing the cornstarch results in unwanted lumps, even when using an electric hand mixer. So, next time, I'll probably pour all the water right away, and dissolve **before** heating it up to thicken it.

Secondly, after sitting on the counter overnight, it's a bit too soft, in my opinion. I want it to be as firm as the cotlets that I could buy. When cut into the small cubes, they do hold their shape, which is good. And also, the cornstarch/confectionery sugar mix doesn't get absorbed, which is also good, but it's just too soft. Could it just be a matter of time that it will actually become firmer by just being stored in a box or sitting open on the counter?

But my biggest issue is that it is just way too sweet, seemingly much sweeter than putting 1 tbsp of plain sugar in my mouth. I think I want to use just 1 cup of sugar because the 4 cups just seems too much. But I'm afraid that just 1 cup of sugar dissolved in the 1 1/2 cups of water won't reach the 240F required to reach the required softball state. Can I just use 3/8 cup of water for that 1 cup of sugar? But then my candy thermometer won't be able to read it because the solution would be too shallow. (I don't have a smaller pan).

So again, primarily, how can I use way less sugar than the recipe states to significantly reduce the sweetness, and achieve the same firmness of cotlets?

Comment: I understand you should mix the cornstarch and water BEFORE heating.

Comment: If you cook it for long enough it will reach soft ball, but whether anything goes wrong in the meantime, and whether you make a sensible quantity, are different questions

Comment: @roetnig - Gradually add water to me means you drop a little, stir, drop a little more, stir, and so on until you've poured all the water, per many videos I've seen when pouring water or oil onto a mixture. The instructions are wrong.

Comment: @Chris H - so you're saying that less amount of sugar dissolved in the water will still reach softball temperature, right?

Comment: Yes, because soft ball is the boiling point of a certain strength of sugar solution, so you evaporate water until you reach that strength

Comment: Adding a whole lot of water to cornstarch on one go is just begging for lumps. I usually add just enough to get it to the "[non-Newtonian Fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Newtonian_fluid)" stage, mix well, then add the rest.

Comment: @brhans. Thank you. That's very helpful to know.